# How to dispose/rollback a BeginTransaction() with several SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a 3 layer structure in my solution, where the two lower ones are the logic layer and the database layer. The database layer consists of all CRUD methods for each entity in my database. And in the logic layer we have CRUD services for each entity database CRUD method (EntityService.Add/Get/Update/Delete -> EntityRepository.Add/Get/Update/Delete).

So here I am trying to do a big save method in services that saves several entities. The method calls several `Add` methods in the logic layer for each entity, which in their turn calls the database `Add` method. I might add that all database CRUD methods ends with `SaveChanges()`. Of course I want the save method to be `Rollbacked` if anything goes wrong so our database don't get unconnected rows, so I have added `BeginTransaction()` to the save method.

Maybe worth mentioning is that after every CRUD we check so that nothing has gone wrong, and if it has we do a return with the returncode and whatnot. These returns happens before `transaction.Commit()`

The save method is structured like this: (Logic Layer)

```
public void SaveMethod(...)
{
 using (var context = _unitOfWork.EntityRepository.GetContext()) //Gets the dbContext
        {
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    Service.Entity1.AddEntity1();
                    
                    Service.Entity2.AddEntity2();

                    //And so on...

                    transaction.Commit();
                 }
                 catch{
                    //Exception handling...
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

The method that gets the context to the Save method transaction: (database layer)

```
     public AniPlanContext GetContext()
    {
        var dbBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        var dbConn = _configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContextConnectionstring"); //Gets the db connection string
        var options = dbBuilder.UseSqlServer(dbConn).Options;

        return new AniPlanContext(options);
    }
```

How an AddEntity method looks like: (Logic layer)

```
public Entity AddClinic(...)
    {
        try
        {
            //Validation....

           Entity entity = _unitOfWork.EntityRepository.Add(
                new Entity
            {
                //Set the attributes...
            });

            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Exception
        }
    }
```

How a database Add looks like: (Database layer)

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(Add)} entity must not be null");
        }

        try
        {
            _context.Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be saved");
        }
    }
```

Anyhow, my issue is that `BeginTransaction` Commits the things that has done their `AddEntity()` even if the save method crashes or fails in any way. Can you help me understand why this is and how I can fix this?

I have tried with `TransactionScope` and it works but when reading several blogposts it sounds like `BeginTransaction()` is the save and more reliant way to go. Of what I have understood, both of these should be `disposed` and `rollbacked` if it does not go through `transaction.Commit` or `scope.Complete`, is that correct?

So to summarize or clarify: I'd like to use `BeginTransaction()` to save several entities to the database but that also rollback / dispose the transaction if anything has gone wrong.

Comment: Ensure you are using the same `DbContext` object. From the code above, it looks like you are mixing `context` and `_context`.

Comment: Don't use several `SaveChanges` to begin with. You wouldn't need an explicit transaction if you used EF as intended - a DbContest *is* a Unit-of-Work. It's meant to collect all changes and apply them only once. If you want to "rollback", just don't call `SaveChanges` before exiting the `using` block. If you want to apply them, `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally, so there's no need for an explicit transaction either

Comment: So to `I'd like to use BeginTransaction() to save several entities` - don't

Comment: In fact, your `Add` can perform 500 DELETEs and 20 UPDATES, precisely because `SaveChanges` stores *all* changes, not just the latest one. That's why the "generic" repository is an **anti**pattern when used with ORMs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, it seems there is no reason for use multiple SaveChanges, but that should not cause the error OP described. It is perfectly safe to call multiple SaveChanges before calling CommitTransaction (safe, not optimal)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was thinking of having a SaveMethod that could be called in the logic layer instead of having a SaveChanges() in each repo.Crud method. Would you say that that is a better way?

Comment: @TomasChabada it's actually **pointless**. Why use a transaction at all when SaveChanges already uses a transaction? The entire design is wrong and causes the problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I know. But SaveChanges => SaveChanges => commit/rollback itself does not produce half results. Either all changes applied or reverted. Save changes causes only temporary dirty written data when used inside Transaction

Comment: @FearlessFox you don't need any of them. The better way is to just not try to impose a low-level repository on top of the high-level ORM. A DbContext *is* a UoW, a DbSet *is* a repository. Read Gunnar Peipman's [No Need for Repositories and Unit of Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) and [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton). The problems with "generic" repositories are known for over 10 years, this isn't something new

Comment: From what you have shown, the `AddEntity` methods seem to swallow exceptions, so not surprisingly the code flows to transaction commit point.

Comment: @TomasChabada then you should understand that the entire design should be scrapped. There may be other connections, multiple contexts involved, in code that wasn't posted. We don't know which context the `Add` methods work with. None of this code would be needed without the "repository" antipattern. And fixing a single bug here won't fix the overall design bugs, the logic errors, or the requirement for long-lived connections and blocking issues this introduces

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: agree

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am taking your advise, read trough the links you shared, and will change the structure of the solution. No more UnitOfWork and no more Repositories :) thank you all for the discussion, it really helped. Everybody needs to read this link https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/.

Answer (score 1):

As @PanagiotisKanavos and @Tomas Chabada agreed upon, it is not the error that is the problem but my solution structure.

This [link](http://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work) provides (for me at least) a new way of seeing the UnitOfWork / Repository structure. Apparently they are not needed, which is completely mindblowing. It is worth reading if you ever happen upon the same issue as I had above. It might not be the transaction that is wrong but how we use EF Core and the DBContext and their transactions.